# What apps are there to backups/share photos and videos online?

Tags: video, photos, photo-sharing, online-backup, online-storage

I'm currently using Picasa but its very limited in space and I think doesn't handle videos.

What other apps are there with similar functionality ?

---

Please no duplicates
Dropbox is already listed.

How much storage is available ?

It would be preferred if there were free.

Comment: You could always buy more storage from Google.

Comment: Google's extra storage is really cheap (I have more space than I need). Picasaweb also supports video.

Comment: 5$ per year for 20GB... it's less than a beer.. so drink one beer less and you have a year free...!! :D Plus, if you don't have the 5$ next year your pictures won't be deleted and you will still have access for as long as you want..!! :)

Comment: Good point, Tks, that 5$ seems a good option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) which gives you 2Gb free.  You can get up to 8Gb free space by introducing friends.

They also offer a paid service:

- 50 Gb $9.99 / month or $99.00 / year
- 100 Gb $19.99 / month or $199.00 / year

You can share folders out and anything put in the dropbox folders gets synced automatically.

There are Mobile Apps for iPhone, Android, Blackberry and iPad.

Another nice feature is that it keeps an archive for 30 days so if you delete something by accident you can always restore it back.

Comment: Up to 10GB actually (it's 8Gb extra space) and up to 18Gb if you're a student :) http://dropbox.com/edu

Comment: @Lipis - Oh yes, thought it was a total of 8Gb.  Didn't know about the student deal - Thats pretty sweet. Cheers

Comment: Very nice app for sync files and folder. More expensive than googles one for additional storage...

Answer (score 3):

[Windows Live SkyDrive](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-skydrive) offers 25GB of free disk space.

Comment: sound good, start trying it.

Comment: It doesn't really works if you have a friend with linux or on your mobile phone... right?

Answer (score 2):

So, since you want a free solution here's my thought on Dropbox vs the Microsoft soluiton.

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) gives you 2GB of storage, nice client apps for multiple platforms, plus web access to your files. You can share those files with whoever you want. A down side for me is that everything you want to syncronize has to be in a single folder... and sometimes that's not possible.

Microsoft has [Live Mesh 2011](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=other) which gives 5GB of storage if you use the web. Let's say you whant to syncrhonize your home and work computers, you don't need the web for that so you are not using any of the 5GBs. Live Mesh has also a cool client app and you can synch up many folders which do not have to be child of a specific common folder. But, once a folder is set for synchronization you can't exclude a child folder... that's a down side specially if you are synchronizing source code.

Microsoft also has [SkyDrive](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-skydrive) where you have up to 25Gbs of storage but you can only aceess thru their web page. They don't even have any API (yet)

Me? I use all of them :)

Comment: They still dont't have an API (and don't plan on releasing one, that would compete with their cloudy storage platform). Though they free Live software can synchronize seemlessly. The picture viewer that comes with the package has a "publish" function that sends all the pictures to the SkyDrive folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Picasa Web storage space is now extended to 'unlimited storage' for photos <2048x2048 resolution if you open a Google+ account, it becomes one of the best solution for photos backup on the cloud.